# Why am I unable to create an object of my class outside stepdefinition

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow, pageobjects

I am just automating a website using SpecFlow+Selenium+pageObject.
When i initialize an object of my SignIn class then i am getting null pointer exception. I tried inside constructor of LoginTest Class(Step definition file) but same error then i moved to first step definition then it is working. The new issue is that i cant use the same object in 2nd step definition since it is initialized locally.

I am adding my code , please tell me what mistake i am making in over all script.

```
namespace UnitTestProject5.Pages
{
    public class SignIn
    {
        public IWebDriver driver;

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using ("//nav[@role='navigation']/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/ul/li[5]/a"))]
        public IWebElement Login { get; set; }

        public IWebElement Username;
        public IWebElement Password;
        public IWebElement Signin;


        public SignIn(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this.driver = driver;
        }

        public void LoginToMyAccount(String username,String password)
        {
            Username.SendKeys(username);
            Password.SendKeys(password);
            Signin.Submit();
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

And..

```
namespace UnitTestProject5
{
    [Binding]
    public class LoginTest 
    {

        IWebDriver driver = null;

        // constants con = new constants();

        [Given(@"Go to website")]
        public void GivenGoToWebsite()
        {
            driver =new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://xero.com");
            SignIn sin = new SignIn(driver);
            PageFactory.InitElements(driver, sin);
            sin.Clicklogin();
        }

        [Given(@"Enter user name & password")]
        public void GivenEnterUserNamePassword()
        {
            sin.
        }

        [When(@"I press submit")]
        public void WhenIPressSubmit()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
        }

        [Then(@"i should be my landing page")]
        public void ThenIShouldBeMyLandingPage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Feature / Scenario:

```
Feature: Successful Login
Scenario: Successful Login
    Given Go to website
    And Enter user name & password
    When I press submit
    Then i should be my landing page
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you're losing the variable between each given-when-then scenario contexts. Each of the methods "Given-When-Then" are executed in a static context and any variables you may have defined in the class are lost between the calls to them. The proper way to adress this is to use the **ScenarioContext** and **FeatureContext** objects. Pseudo example below:

:

```
[Given("Something nice")]
public void WhenIStartSomething()
{
    // Add an inspector  to the current context
    var currentPageInspector = ScenarioContext.Current.Set("PageInspector", new PageInspector());


    // Construct other stuff
    ScenarioContext.Current.Add("signInInstance", SignIn(...));
}


[When("I do something planned")]
public void WhenIDoSomethingPlanned()
{
    var signIn = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<SignIn>();

    // do the action with signIn
}

[Then("I should see the following result")]
public void ThenIShouldSeeTheFollowingResult()
{
    var currentPageInspector = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<PageInspector>();

    currentPageInspector.CurrentPage.Title.ShouldEqual("My Landing Page");
}
```

What you're basically doing is creating a static instance of your PageInspector and SignIn objects that ONLY EXIST as part of the scenario that they are running in. If you have a different scenario where you repeat any of the steps, the ScenarioContext will ensure that you have a different static context for the objects there.

Comment: This is the correct analysis of the issue but the solution is for specflow 1.9. This won't work in 2.0 I don't think due to how things have been changed to accommodate parallel execution of tests. See [this article](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Parallel-Execution/) for the adjustments necessary for v 2.0

Comment: Thanks but sorry to inform you that i am new to C#. I have done the same in Java. Can you give some more informations for understanding it?

Comment: @Pedro , Can you explain me whith above script?